# In d3.js, skip append() for null data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a line graph out of little circle bullets. However, the data has holes in it, which are represented by null's in my array. Naturally, wherever there's no data, there shouldn't be circles. But d3's append() method adds them anyway. How do I avoid this?

Here's a [jsFiddle mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/WxS4a/58/) reproducing my problem exactly.

I'm interested in NOT having that series of circles that lie on the X axis of my graph, since those are all nulls.

Relevant code from the jsfiddle link:

```
svg.selectAll('circle').data(values).enter()
  .append('circle')// <-- I don't want to do this for null's
  .attr('fill', '#c00')
  .attr('r', 3)
  .attr('cx', xi)
  .attr('cy', yFlipped)
```

Comment: Hi , if you find the solution can you please tell me. if i need to stop draw diagonal node from null values. How to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One option is to represent your data differently, so that you aren't dependent on the index to compute the x-coordinate. For example, if you represented each datum as an object (e.g., `{x: 0, y: 0.2840042}`) then you could compute the x-coordinate as `x(d.x)` rather than `x(i)`.

Another option would be to set the radius to zero when the value is null, so the circles are hidden: `circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d == null ? 0 : 3; })`. Or, you could hide the circles: `circle.style("display", function(d) { return d == null ? "none" : null; })`.

You could also remove the null elements after appending them: `circle.filter(function(d) { return d == null; }).remove()`. That would work for the initial creation, but I wouldn't recommend it because the index would change if you reselected the elements later.

Comment: Aside, regarding the zero radius approach - with my large but sparse array, I get much better performance when I create and use a new filtered array via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.


I realize @meetamit wishes to maintain the original indices but thought I'd point out that there may be undesirably performance implications.  Maybe d3 can address this by short circuiting when r <= 0 or implement the 'defined' function for circle?

Comment: I used the `circle.filter(function(d) { return d == null; }).remove()` method for my issue and it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest option is to filter the nulls out of the data being passed in to `.data(…)`, augmenting the data to maintain the index:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(values
    .map(function(v, idx) { return v == null? null : { idx: idx, value: v })
    .filter(function(v) { return v != null })
  )
  .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill', '#c00')
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.idx * 10 }) // or whatever
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.value.y }) // or whatever
```

Note that you can also follow this pattern individual sub-elements, even if they aren't naturally lists. For example, consider a situation where you want to conditionally add a second circle:

```
var circles = [
    { color: 'red', cx: 30, cy: 30, subCircleColor: 'blue' },
    { color: 'blue', cx: 60, cy: 60, subCircleColor: 'green' },
    { color: 'green', cx: 90, cy: 90 },
];

// Create a group which will hold the circles, since the result will
// be:
//    <g class="circles">
//      <circle color="{{ color }}" ... />
//      <circle class="sub-circle" color="{{ subCircleColor }}" ... />
//    </g>
var circlesGroups = svg.selectAll("g.circles")
    .data(circles)
    .enter()
        .append("g").attr({"class": "circles"})

// Add the first circle to the group
circlesGroups
    .append("circle").attr({
        "fill": function(d) { return d.color },
        "r": 20,
        "cx": function(d) { return d.cx },
        "cy": function(d) { return d.cy },
    })

// If there is a subCircleColor, add the second circle to the group
circlesGroups.selectAll("circle.sub-circle")
    .data(function(d) {
        if (d.subCircleColor)
            return [d];
        return [];
    })
    .enter()
        .append("circle").attr({
            "class": "sub-circle",
            "fill": function(d) { return d.subCircleColor; },
            "r": 10,
            "cx": function(d) { return d.cx },
            "cy": function(d) { return d.cy },
        })
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3d6e648k/

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern, which can either delete or hide your circles.

```
// Step 1: hides all circles which are "null"
d3.selectAll(".yourItem")
.data(data)
.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("visibility", function(d,i){
        if(yourFunction(d) == null) return "hidden";
})

// Step 2: optional, deletes all circles which are "hidden"
d3.selectAll("circle[visibility=hidden]").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way if you want to never append it in the first place. I used an if statement inside an .each() and then d3.select(this) to append it to the current item.

```
var data = [9, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1];

var svg = d3.select('#svg').append('svg').attr({'viewBox': '-10 -10 99 20'});

svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter().append('g').each(function (d,i) {
 if(d){
  d3.select(this).append('circle').attr({r:5,cx:(i*9)});
 }else{
  d3.select(this).remove();
 }
});
```

Here is a bin http://jsbin.com/qojifug/edit?js,output

Comment: Although this skips appending a `<circle>`, it still appends a `<g>` as container — just leaves it empty when `d` is 0. While that may be advantageous in case you intend to also append other elements inside that `<g>`, it's not actually skipping appending a `<g>`. Also, in `.selectAll('z')` it should be `.selectAll('g')`, otherwise repeat calls to this code (even if with the same `data`) will append additional `<g>` elements each time.

Comment: Thanks for the review. How about adding an else to remove the g if there is no d?
"else{ d3.select(this).remove() }"

Comment: Yes — calling `.remove()` achieves the result of having only as many `<g>`s as there are non-zeros in `data`. It also keeps `i` in sync with the position of `d` in `data`. But, depending on the larger context, there could be problems with this. For example, if you were to call additional function (e.g. `.attr` or `.remove`) on the *updating* or *exiting* results of this `.data()` join, you might get an error, because some of the elements will have been removed already. Also, if you later re-`selectAll()` the `<g>`s and rejoin them with data, `i` might no longer be in sync with `d`'s array pos.

Comment: Without testing, I'm not sure that the problematic examples I pointed out would actually occur as described. I'm mainly going by the assumption that if you ever `.remove()` a member of a d3 selection without using the *exiting* selection for it, you could have issues. Since I posted this question (5 years ago, geez) I've basically adopted mbostock's recommendation (on this page) to almost never rely on `i` for data representation and instead using `d` as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter it.

```
values.filter(function(el){return el !== null;})
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just removes those elements from the array, which affects the index, i that's passed into my attr() setting functions. I need the index to remain unchanged, because it's what I use to calculate x positions.

Comment: This was actually my problem and I felt silly not even thinking about just filtering out. I guess I was so caught up in "How does d3 do this?" that I didn't think :)