# Omit null values in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am stuck in a project drawing a line from JSON data containing some null-values.

I started a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/scm60/pafs5x4m/

I found a possible solution here:
[In d3.js, skip append() for null data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826180/in-d3-js-skip-append-for-null-data), suggesting to add

```
circle.filter(function(d) { return d == null; }).remove()
```

But this doesn't work in my example.

Any suggestions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three issues here:

First, you don't have a selection named `circle`. So, let's create it:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    //etc...
```

Second, after the `forEach`, you don't have null values for `gewicht` anymore, only zeros.

Third, it has to be `d.gewicht`, not `d`:

```
circle.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.gewicht == 0; 
})
.remove();
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y25mLtue/

PS: If you want to remove the lines going to zero (null) as well, you need `line.defined()`. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/97ao8v16/

Comment: Thanks! Learned a lot from this.